# Apache mod rewrite is adding file extension automatically on mac

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Me and my colleague are using apache on windows(2.4.18) and apache on mac(2.4.16). We are working on save project using SVN.

All requests, except some images are redirected to index.php using following .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.woff2)$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

When accessing "/c-panel/folder/something" from windows my path param in $_GET is exactly as it should be "/c-panel/folder/something". When accessing same url on mac path param is "/c-panel/folder/something.php". Have in mind that something.php file actually exists on both OS. So why on MAC apache is adding .php at the end, when it should not and when does it comes from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is due to `MultiViews` option turned on on OSX Apache. You can turn it off using this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: `Options -MultiViews` turns that option off?

Comment: Ah I see .. +1 ... Just one thing, that's because there is `-` before `MultiViews`, So that dash makes it off? *(sorry I'm newbie in this field)*

Comment: Right `Options +MultiViews` turns it on, on the other hand

Comment: `-MultiViews` removes it from the `Options` set, whilst `+MultiViews` adds it. Omitting either the `+/-` resets the `Options` set to only contain `MultiViews`.